# Evaluating and redirecting http requests

Tags: proxy, http, transparent-proxy

I am trying to evaluate traffic on port 80 to determine whether or not if we need to redirect a request, or pass it through, while being transparent.

Scenario:

- User connects to our system via Wifi.
- User navigates to example.com.
- Somehow I need to evaluate the request to example.com by looking at
  the users IP and User-Agent. If both are valid values. Pass the
  request through, If not redirect them to a splash page.

Anyone have any ideas on how this could be implemented?

Comment: A common term for what I think you're trying to do is to build a 'captive portal'.  Searching for that term you should be able to find a huge amount of information on how to get started.